# Re-assigning the value of enumerate operation in python to second variable doesn't gives the same result

Tags: python

Below is my code.

```
l1 = "Hello World"
x1 = enumerate(l1)
print(x1)
print(type(x1))

x2 = list(x1)
x3 = list(x1)
print(x2)
print(x3)
```

the output of the above code is as follows:

```
<enumerate object at 0x000002119D35D9A8>
<class 'enumerate'>
[(0, 'H'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'l'), (3, 'l'), (4, 'o'), (5, ' '), (6, 'W'), (7, 'o'), (8, 'r'), (9, 'l'), (10, 'd')]
[]
```

the problem is that X3 is not having the same value as X2 is having... instead X3 becomes a blank list.

i want to know the reason as to why it is working like this.

Comment: Because `enumerate` is a generator.

Comment: Try this `x3=x2[:]` should work.